# Django : Display uploaded image with media

Tags: django

I would like to display in my template the `uploaded picture` for each object. I'm getting an issue because there is an error with `media` path when I click over `picture url`.

I have in my model :

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    ...
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', verbose_name=_('cover page'))
```

Then, I have in my settings part :

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/myapp/'
```

Now, in my template file, I display the picture like this :

```
{% if item.cover %}
    <td>
        <a href="{{item.cover.url}}" target="_blank">
            <img class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" src="{{item.cover.url}}" alt="{{item.cover}}">
        </a>
    </td>
{% else %}
    <td></td>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

The template page url is : `http://localhost:8000/crud/publication/list/`
And when I click on my picture link, I get : `http://localhost:8000/crud/publication/list/media/media/couverture_qZQKLED.jpg`

It's false and I should get :

```
http://localhost:8000/media/couverture_qZQKLED.jpg
```

Then, I would like ti replace visible elements just by a glyphicon.

Could you help me ?

In my urls.py file, I have :

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: should not it be `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`?

Comment: @AhmedHosny And how I can juste display my glyphicon and when I click over it, it displays my picture in new tab with `blank` ? Your comment about `/media` works

Comment: add this to urls.py if you havent done that yet.
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` as i can see you mentioned that already then it should display image in new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct configuration for media files in settings.py

```
# Media files, uploaded by user
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Template

```
<a href="{{item.cover.url}}" target="_blank">
    <!-- An alt tag in span makes no sense, so you can use title tag if you want. -->
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" title="{{item}}"></span>
    <!-- OR show item's str inside span -->
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">{{item}}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You're right ! And How I can replace picture by glyphicon and show picture in new tab when I click on glyphicon ?

Comment: try removeing `src` attribute from `img` tag. In my opinion use `span` tag to show glyphicon instead of `img`.

Answer (score 2):

you have add the  upload_to='media/', in the image fields so it will create one more folder inside your media root. Django already media in image path. complete path become
mediaurl+folderpath

```
cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='other_folder_name', verbose_name=_('cover page'))
```

and

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

because it take relative path, without start with /

```
<a href="{{item.cover.url}}" target="_blank">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" alt="{{item.cover}}"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: You're right ! And How I can replace picture by glyphicon and show picture in new tab when I click on glyphicon ?

Comment: you can use the anchor tag for that. url of anchor tag will be image url.